# include XPathSelectElement in portable class library

Tags: c#, xml, linq, xpath, portable-class-library

How can I use `XPathSelectElement` in a portable class library? When I try to include `System.Xml.XPath` assembly in the project, I get the following error:

> The type 'System.Xml.Linq.XElement' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'System.Xml.Linq, Version=2.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'.

My portable class libraries already have a reference to `System.Xml.Linq`.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xpath.extensions_methods%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is showing that, as of .NET 4.5, these extension methods are not supported in Portable Class Libraries. If they were supported, they would display a [image: PCL icon] image. However, it looks like Microsoft did provide [a Nuget package](http://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Xml.XPath.SL4/) that provides at least some of the functionality in the System.Xml.XPath namespace.

Answer (score 0):

Because `XPathSelectElement` is declared in `System.Xml.Linq.dll`, you should also reference it.

More details can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb351355%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: I have already referenced it in the project and it still gives the same error.

Comment: Are you using a `Parse` method to get an instance of XElement? If so, could you try to do this: `(XDocument.Parse(str) as XDocument).XPathSelectElement`?