# HtmlAgilityPack, PCL, without XPath: How to get all elements by class?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, html-agility-pack

A prototype I'm working on needs to extract a deep-nested IFrame inside a website. I need to find all elements containing a class, but XPath is not available in the PCL distribution of HtmlAgilityPack, so [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22974491/htmlagilitypack-get-all-elements-by-class) does not work. The other approach of using .Descendants() as [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29689499/htmlagilitypack-pcl-linq) suggests doesn't seem to work, either, because I tried and Descendants() doesn't seem to consider children of children, or if it does, I don't know how to.

The [site's](https://ledrenche.fr/2016/10/selection-entree-masters-1019/) data structure is like this:

```
html
  body
    div class mh-container
      div class mh-wrapper
        div class mh-main
          div id main-content
           article class post  
             div class entry-content <- has multiple (2) divs with os_poll
               div class os_poll
                 div class os_widget_container <- TARGET
                   iframe name os_frame <- need data of the 'src' attribute
```

My goal is to get all elements with the class of os_poll, and then access the iframe and get their src data. Since XPath doesn't work and I don't know how to navigate the nodes to get children of children (I'm new to HAP), I don't know how to deal with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a way to find elements by class in PCL projects. But you will have to use [AngleSharp](https://github.com/AngleSharp/AngleSharp/wiki/Examples) for this, not HtmlAgilityPack, because [XPath is not available in PCL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20651431/include-xpathselectelement-in-portable-class-library). Check the AngleSharp link for more.

Select all elements by class in AngleSharp:

```
string html;
using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
    string = await client.GetStringAsync("http://your.content.com/some.html");
}
var parser = new HtmlParser();
var doc = parser.Parse(html);
var divs = doc.All.Where(e = > e.LocalName == "div" && e.ClassList.Contains("your-class"));
```

Note: don't use the data from the site I linked above, because the website above needs JavaScript for os_poll elements to be added, it will not work. That's another problem entirely and is outside of the scope of this question.